Atomic transaction with more than one model
I have a view that saves the data in two different models "Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacao" and "Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacaoCentro", however if an error occurs when creating "Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacaoCentro", it is not giving the rollback so as not to also create "Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacao", what am I doing wrong in this view?
from .serializers import FuncionarioAlocacaoSerializer
from auditlog.context import set_actor
from client.app_eliel.models import Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacao, Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacaoCentro
from django.db import transaction
from microservices.serializers import ActorSerializer
from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication, TokenHasReadWriteScope
from project_datafit.utils import log_error
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json
import re

@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([OAuth2Authentication])
@permission_classes([TokenHasReadWriteScope])
def funcionarioAlocacao_create_api(request):

    actor_serializer = ActorSerializer(data=request.data)
    funcionarioAlocacao_serializer = FuncionarioAlocacaoSerializer(data=request.data)

    try:

        actor_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        actor = actor_serializer.validated_data['actor']
        matricula = funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.validated_data['matricula']
        data_inicio = funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.validated_data['data_inicio']
        data_fim = funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.validated_data['data_fim']
        obs = funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.validated_data.get('obs') 
        centros_data = funcionarioAlocacao_serializer.validated_data.get('centros', [])

        with transaction.atomic(): 
            with set_actor(actor):
                try:
                    funcionarioAlocacao = Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacao(Matricula=matricula, DataInicio=data_inicio, DataFim=data_fim, Obs=obs)
                    funcionarioAlocacao.save()

                    for centro_data_str in centros_data:
                        centro_data = json.loads(centro_data_str)
                        centro = centro_data.get('centro')
                        porcentagem = centro_data.get('porcentagem')

                        Eliel_FuncionarioAlocacaoCentro.objects.create(
                            IdAlocacao=funcionarioAlocacao,
                            CodCentro=centro,
                            Peso=porcentagem
                        )
        
                    return Response({'success': 'Alocação feita com sucesso'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                except Exception as e:
                    log_error(request.path, str(e), actor)
                    return Response({'error': 'Erro ao alocar funcionário'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            
    except ValidationError as e:
        error_message = str(e.detail)
        error_message = re.search(r"ErrorDetail\(string='([^']*)'", error_message).group(1)
        return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

I want the atomic transaction to rollback if an error occurs, to create both model elements or not create any if there is an error

Please note that for rolling back a transaction you need to raise an error somewhere!
Since you're catching all exceptions, it's not working as it should be! It can be different based on your requirements but maybe something like:
From rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
And then in your exception block do something like:
raise ValidationError("some errors")
The status code of your API will be 400 then (again it can be some other exceptions but it has to be raised in order to roll back transactions), and all of your transactions will be rolled back I assume.
This raise also needs to be in with transaction.atomic(): block!
